# caret R: determine performance on entire training data set after tuning parameters have been selected

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm using R caret and I'm a bit confused about how to obtain the performance metrics (RMSE and R-Squared in my case) after the tuning parameters have been selected and the **entire** training data set has been evaluated using these parameters.

Here's the output of part of a *train* model

```
eXtreme Gradient Boosting
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 5 times)
Summary of sample sizes: 1771, 1769, 1772, 1770, 1770, 1770, ...
Resampling results across tuning parameters:
   lambda  alpha  nrounds  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE
   0e+00   0e+00   50      1.964635  0.6504540  1.269607

   and ~25 more tuning parameters ...

   1e-01   1e-01  150      1.970099  0.6517576  1.252826

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were nrounds = 50, lambda = 1e-04, alpha = 1e-04 and eta = 0.3
```

OK so far.  I think I understand the RMSE and Rsquared for the resampling data and how the tuning parameters are selected.

My question how can I get the RMSE and RSquared when the tuning parameters are applied to the entire training dataset?
Is it the performance metrics above?

There's a function called *getTrainPerf* and according to the documentation, "The function getTrainPerf returns a one row data frame with the resampling results for the chosen model".  This is just an easy way to get the best resampling tuning.

Am I overthinking this ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question. For example, include the code you used for `caret::train()`, and a subset of the data.

Comment: Train set performance is not very informative, if it was life would be much simpler. Additionally if you get the hyper-parameters such as you did with `xgb` consider attempting some additional combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Repredicting the training set isn't a good idea. The results that you get from `getTrainPerf` are probably a good estimate of how well your model would work on the entire training set.

> Am I overthinking this ?

A bit, yes. It is fairly complex though.